# How to make callback function in the right way PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I have a class

```
 class MyClass {

     public function functionOne(User $user) {
        $user->startProcess(function ($data) {
           $this->makeUpdate($data);
        });
     }

     protected function makeUpdate($data)
     {
        //... do something  
     }
 }



 $myClass = new MyClass();
 $myClass->functionOne($user);
```

When I run this code, I have an error

> **BadMethodCallException** Method App\MyClass::makeUpdate does not exist.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why you don't pass something to `functionOne`?

Comment: @u_mulder I am sorry, I've fixed it

Comment: Your code is working on my local.

Answer (score 0):

It is works with below code

```
$data = $user->startProcess();
$this->makeUpdate($data);
```

instead of

```
$user->startProcess(function ($data) {
    $this->makeUpdate($data);
});
```